# Trouble with LEFT JOINS in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to join some tables in mysql, the last table I am trying to join has multiple possible matches but I want the first in a series or user order.  I keep getting a null result for mi.fileName and cant really figure out why.

CODE:

```
SELECT          catalog_items.*, 
                pages.pageTitle, 
                pages.pageDesc, 
                pages.urlID, 
                siteUrls.url, 
                mi.fileName 
FROM            catalog_items  
LEFT OUTER JOIN pages 
ON              pages.id = catalog_items.page_id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN siteUrls 
ON              pages.urlID = siteUrls.id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT   fileName, urlID 
                 FROM     mediaItems AS mi 
                 ORDER BY sortVal ASC LIMIT 1) as mi 
ON              mi.urlID = pages.urlID  
WHERE           catalog_items.active = 1
```

Comment: Your subquery is not "getting the first in each series", it is getting one of the records with the lowest sortVal. If you want to "first" fileName for each urlID, that is a more complicated query, involving nested subqueries or a potentially inefficient correlated subquery in the select clause.

Comment: maybe better to use a view in this instance?